# Using a 2.0 framework assembly in a 4.5 framework WebApi project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a 'core' assembly with all the logic, and it uses a 3rd party component written in 2.0.  When I try to run my WebApi (4.0) project (4.5 framework) that exposes the core functionality, I get the following error:

**Could not load file or assembly 'Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.**

I created a test console application,and changed the startup tag in the app.config to use legacy runtime, it works.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
```

What is the corresponding change in a web.config?

Comment: Run with `<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="2.0"/>` inside system.web tags. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: When I tried using the controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion change, from 4.0 to 2.0, it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Can be an application pool issue? Have you tried to enable 32 bits app on it?

Comment: The 3rd party component has both a 32 and 64 bit dll.  I'm using 64bit, and per the company's doc, I have specified platform to be x64, since they say that "Any CPU" doesn't work.

Comment: I believe @PiLHA is wrong. The `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion` attribute only controls the HTML generated by ASP.NET's WebControls. It has nothing to do with CLR assembly runtime compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the common issue when you build for the incorrect architecture. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648213/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-xxx-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attempt-was).

Comment: I looked at each project to verify that the platform was x64.  When I build, the output shows **Release x64** for all projects.

Comment: I'm back to trying to prove that I'm building x64 for everything.  I decided to make a new solution.  I created a MVC4 application with WebAPI.  When I start it, it works.  I then tried to change from AnyCPU to x64, and it blow up with **Could not load file or assembly 'MvcWebApi' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.**  I can't trust that I'm properly setting the platform correctly, even though build output displays "Debug x64".

Comment: I switched the test solution, that has only 1 empty WebApi, to x86 and it works.  More testing to come.

Comment: Hmm, switched it back to x64 and it worked.  I'm trying to prove that I'm correctly switching platforms...   :/  I switch my other project to x32 and it works.  But I suspect it will work in x64, it's just likely I'm not doing it properly.  Researching....

Comment: When performing unit tests on VS 2012 we must also consider the target platform for the test engine (TEST > Test Settings > Default Processor Architecture).

Comment: I have finally determined that it is a Target Platform issue.  I wasn't able to get x64 working, but x32 does.  Once I get things flushed out, I'll likely work with the vendor to get 64 bit working.

Comment: I was able to get it working with 64bit. 32bit or AnyCPU works.  64bit doesn't.  It turns out that VS2012 doesn't support running IIS Express 64bit.  I had to hack a registry key to allow it.  Here is the article: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3254745-allow-for-iis-express-64-bit-to-run-from-visual-st