# Fix: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#, exception

While trying add *.dll "AWSREMOTELIB" from my project, I encountered this problem...

[image: screenshot of BadImageFormatException]

What does this `BadFormatException` mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'xxx' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648213/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-xxx-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attempt-was)

Comment: Go to options -> web projects and check "use the 64 bit version..."

Answer (score 13):

Right click on your project and go to Properties. Then in the Build section change the Platform target to x64.

Comment: It would help if the IIS error would just say that...

Answer (score 10):

> A DLL or executable is loaded as a 64-bit assembly, but it contains 32-bit features or resources. For example, it relies on COM interop or calls methods in a 32-bit dynamic link library.
>   To address this exception, set the project's Platform target property to x86 (instead of x64 or AnyCPU) and recompile.

Check this link, it may be a platform problem : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of helpful advice in [Could not load file or assembly ... An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format (System.BadImageFormatException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a)
If the problem is IIS project - C# Any CPU and part of the project is 32 bit c++ project then all of those in the link won't work- because 32 bit c++ cannot be changed- the solution is bitness see the screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpOwH.png) - in "Apply server settings to all users(store in project file)